# Is it Possible to Preload Multiple ads in Android?

Tags: android, google-ad-manager

Our application consists of five routes. Each time a user navigates to a route, an `AdManagerinterstitialAd` will pop up.

Five routes means five different types of `adRequest` properties, so each route will display a different ad:

```
 AdManagerInterstitialAd.load(
     this,
     "myAdUnitId",
     new AdManagerAdRequest.Builder().build(), // << This may be different each time
     new AdManagerInterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull AdManagerInterstitialAd ad) {
             adManagerInterstitialAd = ad;
             adManagerInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                 fullScreenContentCallback);
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError adError) {
             // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
         }
     });
```

Usually, one would preload the ad for a better user experience.

**Question:** Is it possible to preload **multiple** ads, and then show each and one of them accordingly?

Comment: It is indeed possible to use Multiple Ads, but then there’s a possibility of wasted ads as well. Better to use a single ad unit & use Firebase Analytics to log where the Ad was shown.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would it be an issue if there are wasted ads? And if so, for who?

Comment: You lose revenue if the ads are pre-loaded but not shown to the users. Your show-rate will drop due to this.

Comment: @Darshan Thank you. Could you please attach a source? I can't find this information anywhere in the AdManager docs. Additionally, it doesn't really makes sense to me why it would be considered lost revenue. The whole goal of preloading is creating a smooth transition between the app content and the ad, it's not like Google is going to fine me for every unconsumed ad. Am I missing something? Again thanks for replying.

Comment: Revenue is generated on impressions and clicks, not on loads & pre-loads. If you just request an ad and keep it as is or it is not shown (wasted), you lose revenue.

Comment: Got it now. So from my understanding, Google doesn't care how many ads I preload, I just lose revenue if the ads are going to waste(loaded and not shown) - is this correct?